# How attach a dataframe as excel in email and send that attachment from python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, email, smtp

I have a file which is generated and stored inside a S3 bucket in AWS.
I want a sent this S3 file as excel as attachment in email send using python how can do it.

I was successfully was able sent email without the attachment.

**My code**

```
import os
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
role = get_execution_role()
bucket='cotydata'

data_key = 'modeloutput'+'.csv'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)
output_key='UI_'+input_date
output_bucket='model-output-ui'
# Insert weather api key here 
api_key= 'key'
#read modeloutput and prepare dataframe
modeloutput = pd.read_csv(data_location)
df = modeloutput.to_excel("Outpout.xls")

# import necessary packages
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

# create message object instance
msg = MIMEMultipart()
password = "password"
msg['From'] = "riskradar@gmail.com"
msg['To'] = "abc@gmail.com"
msg['Subject'] = "Messgae"
filename = df
f = file(filename)
attachment = MIMEText(f.read(),'xls')
msg.attach(attachment)
# attach image to message body


server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')

server.starttls()

# Login Credentials for sending the mail
server.login(msg['From'], password)

server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to generate a pandas dataframe out of the xls file.

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')    

fp = open(data_location, 'rb')
record = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
record.set_payload(fp.read())
encode_base64(record)
record.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment',
                          filename="what_ever_header_you_want.xls")
msg.attach(record)
```

And the rest is as you wrote it.. That should do the trick.

If you'd like to send a dataframe as an excel file, then you can use the to_excel() method and pass the file's absolute path to the block of code above.

Comment: Its not still working. Basically I want read the excel from S3 and then do some data manipulation and  attach the xls.

Comment: try just passing server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg) instead of msg.as_string(). Make sure that you've saved the xls file and passed the right location.

Comment: Getting now this error :TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not NoneType